# DisplayAlert doesn't show the buttons

Tags: android, xamarin

I have an Xamarin.Forms application, and I want to show the user a Dialog Box with 2 options, one to accept and one to cancel.
But DisplayAlert is not showing the buttons correctly.
This is my code, I have tried WITH and WITHOUT the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    var answer = await DisplayAlert("BITEST", "Are you sure to make a BITEST?", "YES", "NAH");
                    if (answer)
                    {
                        //Do something
                    }
                }
```

And [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MkBJ.jpg) is the result on Android. It looks like the Actions are invisible or the button and the labels are also white. [Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAz0p.jpg) when tap is hold over the buttons

Any ideas?

I tested this only on my phone with Android 10

Edit1: Also tested on tablet with Android 6 and the issue persists

Edit2: Also tested DisplayPromptAsync and A similar problem ocurrs. If I stap tapping everywhere, a cancel button is highlighted, but the Confirm is not [EVIDENCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqZtC.png)

Edit3: I have compiled the Xamarin [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/Pop-ups) on my devices and works fine.

Edit4: I have tried changing the color of the themes, the custom renderers, and everything that had the White color. But the problem persists

Comment: Did you try to test the app on Android emulator ?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inside the Android Styles Themes. The colorAccent was #FFFFFF, that is why I didn't find it when searching for the word "White"

Comment: I know, but I have to wait 48hs before accepting my own answer :)